# Form Submitting Button Not Working When using jQuery hide/show function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I have form and users can show/hide it using jQuery.

**Problem** : After user click show/hide (arrow icon) form submission will work **only one time**. I mean after that when I click form submit button not working.

**What I found** : Seems like having '#' in URL related to this problem.

How to solve this issue?

Jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/damithruwan1234/t795ewx3/2/ (You can't test it from this because jsfiddle not allow the get method )

Full code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#hide_search").click(function(){
  $("#search_panel").hide(1000);
    $("#show_search").show();
    $("#hide_search").hide();
});

$("#show_search").click(function(){
  $("#search_panel").show(1000);
    $("#show_search").hide();
    $("#hide_search").show();
});
});
</script>


</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2" id="search_panel">
  <form action="">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" value="dfdf" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pwd" value="ssds" placeholder="Enter password" name="pwd">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="SEARCH">
  </form>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
 <a href="#" id="hide_search">
 <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa fa-angle-up fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
</a>

 <a href="#" id="show_search" style="display: none;">
 <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
  <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
  <i class="fa fa fa-angle-down fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
</span>
</a>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to remove the `href='#'` in `a` tags

Comment: @prasad I tried.  If it is remove from `<a href="#" id="hide_search">` show/hide function won't works.

Comment: Only remove the `href` not whole `a tag` see this https://jsfiddle.net/t795ewx3/3/

Comment: @prasad  First, I removed only `#`. Then as you suggested I remove `href="#"`part working fine :-) Thanks for the help :-) Do you have any idea that why it is not working when URL has `#` mark?

Comment: I think so.if you click `a` the `#` value updated to the url like `.com#`.`#` prevent the next page redirection.its only perform the same page.That why its restrict the submit.if you applying submit path url is next with `#`.its have some path problem `com#/aftersubmit.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `preventDefault()` on the hide/show click event. Use the below modified script. (The actual issue is when you click hide/show button it will add '#' on the URL, that is why unable to submit your form using 'Get' method)

```
$("#hide_search").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  $("#search_panel").hide(1000);
    $("#show_search").show();
    $("#hide_search").hide();
});

$("#show_search").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
  $("#search_panel").show(1000);
    $("#show_search").hide();
    $("#hide_search").show();
});
```

Comment: Thanks :-) Do you have any idea that why unable to submit  when URL has '#'?

Comment: Because 'Get' method will pass the form values as URL query string... but anything after '#' will not be submitted (in your form when you click the hide/show link it is adding '#' at the end of the URL and all the form values added after '#' when you submit the form. That is why its not working) and it will work on 'POST' method.

Answer (score 0):

You should change hide/show buttons href attribute like this,

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);"
```

or you can do something like this in jquery,

```
$('a[href="#"]').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

It's doesn't work probably because of hash changed. If you use this ways hash doesn't changed.